# POSTGIS display polygon

Tags: polygon, postgis

I'm trying to visualize a simple poligon exploiting open layer retrieving data from postGis database. I'm using as SRS EPSG:404000 wildcard 2D cartesian plane.

I have a polygons: 
 "POLYGON((308.2488 254.05,924.7464 254.05,308.2488 84.6856,924.7464 84.6856,308.2488 254.05))"

Why the displayed polygon has a strange shape formed by two opposites tringles with coinciding vertex? The shape could be a simple rectangle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's the way it's defined: lower right, lower left, upper right, upper left, lower right.
If you want it to be a simple rectangle change the points position like this `POLYGON((308.2488 254.05, 924.7464 254.05, 924.7464 84.6856, 308.2488 84.6856, 308.2488 254.05))`.